# Calling ajax function by multiple activities

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've checkboxes and dropdown list.

I call ajax like this (only for checkboxes)

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {

        $.ajax({
        ...
            }
        });
    });
```

Is it possible to do this in one jquery function (also listen to dropdown element which is selected) or do I've to write another function with different ajax call? I'd prefer first choice. How to achieve this?

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what you are looking for. I'm a bit confused!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that by use **jQuery** miltiselector which is separating two element using ',', please follow below code::

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("input[type=checkbox], select#mySelect").on("change", function() {
        $.ajax({
        ...
        });
    });
});
```

Element selector whatever you want you can change as yourself.

Another way is you can give `selectox` & `checkbox` same class (like: ajaxFire) and use it as below::

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $(".ajaxFire").on("change", function() {
        $.ajax({
        ...
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could attach a class to both the checkbox and dropdown elements, and then select the class with jQuery.

```
$(".respond").on("change", function() { 
    $.ajax({ ... } }); 
});
```